# How to make a selectAll checkbox and triggering every function of ng-click on every checkbox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, underscore.js, lodash

I have some code that when you click a checkbox, it will perform ng-click. Here is the JS of it.

```
$scope.selectTitle = function(evt, selected){
        evt.stopPropagation();
        var filtered = _.findWhere($scope.selectedTitles, {id: selected.id});
        var index = _.indexOf($scope.selectedTitles, selected);
        if(selected === filtered){
            $scope.selectedTitles.splice(index, 1)
        }
        else{
            $scope.selectedTitles.push(selected);
        }
        console.log('titles', $scope.selectedTitles, 'filtered', filtered, 'index', index);
     };
```

It was in a table with ng-repeat with also ng-click code so I used `.stopPropagation()` to prevent the activating of ng-click function of the table.

Now I need to made a select all checkbox. Here is my code.

```
$scope.selectAll = function (filteredTitles) {
        if ($scope.selectedAll) {
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedAll = true;
        }
        _.forEach(filteredTitles, function(cpPortfolioItem) {
            cpPortfolioItem.Selected = $scope.selectedAll;
            if(cpPortfolioItem.Selected){
                $scope.selectTitle();
            }
     });
```

When I run it. there is an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined`.

I can't remove the stopPropagation because it prevents what I said earlier. Can you give me suggestions on how I can select all the checkbox and call the ng-click function of each checkbox? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the intent if you've selected all previously, redoing it will deselect all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts.

Why add to scope with selectedAll?  Should just be a private var inside the controller.

```
var selectedAll = false;
$scope.selectAll = function(){
      selectedAll = !selectedAll; // quick toggle.
      _.forEach(filteredTitles, function(title){
                    title.isSelected = selectedAll;
       }
}
```

Then your checkbox should just hook right into the title.isSelected state.  It would be rather easy to change that individually or with the selectAll.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

```
<input ng-checked="title.isSelected" .../>
```

Where 'title' is really your ng-repeat data object.

Also I'd suggest using a directive inside your ng-repeat.

Sample directive:

```
angular.module('appName')
    .directive('portfolioItem', function() {
        return{
            restrict:'E',  // Element only style
            replace:true,
            templateUrl:'portfolioItem.view.html',
            scope:{
                data:'='  // binds the attribute into your scope
            }
            // You can add a controller here as well. 
        };
    });
```

Then create a script ng-template for "portfolioItem.view.html"

```
<script ng-template="portfolioItem.view.html">
    <section class="item">
     {{data}}  
     <input ng-checked="data.isSelected" ... />
    </section>
</script>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script

If I could help you out a weee bit more.  I think your select item function should be changed.  Push your data into a factory, which can then be your backbone across all controllers.  This is what we do, reduces your watchers and increases your ability to work with your data.

```
 angular.module('appName')
        .factory('DataManager', DataManager);

    function DataManager($log, $timeout, ItemModel) {
        var mngr, config = getConfig();  // any default values

        $log.debug('DataManager Init');

        mngr = {
            CurrentSearchTerm: null,
            Items: [],
            Abort: abort,
            GetData: getData,  // Function call to get data.
            GetMoreResults: getMoreResults
        };

        function getData(){
            dataService.getData().then(function(response){
             //  ...parse data, etc...loop and :
             mngr.Items.push(parsedDataItem);
            };
        }


        return mngr;
   }
```

Then your controller will repeat off the DataManager.Items (or filter it will Underscore or Angular).  make sense?

Comment: what do you mean in "Also I'd suggest using a directive inside your ng-repeat."? here is my code. 

`ng-repeat='cpPortfolioItem in filteredTitles'`

Comment: Usually each of the item's you are repeating need some self contained logic.  Angular's magic is in directives.  So each of the cpPortfolioItem could be assigned to <portofiltioitem data="cpPortfolioItem"/>  and that is a directive with a "template" for what you want assigned and done for that data object.  You would also not need an evt.stopPropagation anymore as well.

Comment: oh. That was some sort of work. This answer was very informative. However I am new on using angularJS. Maybe some other time I will study about that. Can I have another favor? Can you gave me a solution on how to trigger the ng-click of every checkbox after the selectAll() method was called? Also the stopPropagation thing is killing me.

Comment: If done right you need to realize that things are two-way bound.  So if your main controller sets the data of "isSelected=true" for all items, then all the check boxes will automatically be "checked" becaues the boolean evaluation is then true, not false.  You don't need to do anything else.

Comment: You could add a function in the factory for "get selected" which just returns the filtered items where "isSelected" === true.  I'm also trying to say I don't think (believe) that selectAll should ever trigger the ng-Click of the other checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the prettiest solution but, this does two things, only deal with `evt` if defined, and passes the element into `selectTitle` from `selectAll`. This is the solution that changes your code the least. in general you should be able to get away without `selectTitle` at all using just ng-model on your checkbox.

```
$scope.selectTitle = function(evt, selected){
    if(evt) evt.stopPropagation();
    var filtered = _.findWhere($scope.selectedTitles, {id: selected.id});
    var index = _.indexOf($scope.selectedTitles, selected);
    if(selected === filtered){
        $scope.selectedTitles.splice(index, 1)
    }
    else{
        $scope.selectedTitles.push(selected);
    }
    console.log('titles', $scope.selectedTitles, 'filtered', filtered, 'index', index);
 };
```

--

```
$scope.selectAll = function (filteredTitles) {
        if ($scope.selectedAll) {
            $scope.selectedAll = false;

        } else {
            $scope.selectedAll = true;

        }
        _.forEach(filteredTitles, function(cpPortfolioItem) {
            cpPortfolioItem.Selected = $scope.selectedAll;
            if(cpPortfolioItem.Selected){
                $scope.selectTitle(null, cpPortfolioItem);
            }
     })};
```